# ItextPDF migration to pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I have the following code which i am migrating from itextpdf to pdfbox..

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/displaypdf.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public void displaypdf(HttpServletRequest p_objRequest, HttpServletResponse p_objResponse,
                    @RequestParam("filename") String p_sFilename) throws Exception {
                if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.DISPLAYPDF);
                }
                String l_sReportName;
                Blob l_bContent = null;
                String l_sTcn = (String) p_objRequest.getSession().getAttribute(ClmSrConstant.TCN);
                ServletOutputStream l_objServletOutputStream = p_objResponse.getOutputStream();
                Map<String, Object> l_mapConfigFile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//PDDocument doc = null;
    
                Document document = null;
                try {
                    l_mapConfigFile = m_objClinicalService.retrieveMap(l_sTcn);
                    Iterator<String> it = l_mapConfigFile.keySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        String key = it.next();
                        if (key.contains(p_sFilename)) {
                            l_bContent = (Blob) l_mapConfigFile.get(key);
                        }
                    }
                    l_sReportName = p_sFilename;
                    if (l_bContent != null) {
//doc = new PDDocument();
                    //PDPage firstpage = new PDPage();
                    //doc.addPage(firstpage);
                        document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, l_objServletOutputStream);
                        document.open();
                        document.addTitle(l_sReportName);
                        p_objResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        byte[] l_bytes = l_bContent.getBytes(1, (int) l_bContent.length());
                        InputStream l_inptStrm = l_bContent.getBinaryStream();
                        PdfReader l_pdfReader = new PdfReader(l_inptStrm, l_bytes);
                        PdfContentByte l_cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
                        PdfImportedPage l_page;
                        int l_currentPageNumber = 0;
                        int l_pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                        while (l_pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < l_pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                            if (l_pageOfCurrentReaderPDF > 0) {
                                document.newPage();
                            }
                            l_pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                            l_currentPageNumber++;
                            l_page = writer.getImportedPage(l_pdfReader, l_pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                            l_cb.addTemplate(l_page, 0, 0);
                        }
                        writer.freeReader(l_pdfReader);
                    } else {
                        p_objResponse.setContentType(ClmSrConstant.TXT_CNTN_TYP);
                        p_objResponse.getOutputStream().print(ClmSrConstant.NLP_REPORT_ERROR);
                    }
        
                    l_objServletOutputStream.flush();
                    if (document != null) {
                        document.close();
                    }
                    l_objServletOutputStream.close();
        
                } catch (Exception exExp) {
                    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        LOGGER.error(ClmSrDebugConstant.EXCEP_DISPLAYPDF, exExp);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am not getting that how can i convert this line

> PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, l_objServletOutputStream);
> PdfReader l_pdfReader = new PdfReader(l_inptStrm, l_bytes);
> PdfContentByte l_cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF

for further conversion.

Please find that i am using now pdfbox -- but unable to find PDFwriter and PDFReader in PDFBOX

Comment: The PDFBox and iText architectures differ substantially. Thus, there usually is no line-by-line code conversion but you have to distill from the original code what exactly it does, and then write a converted routine that does the same using the other library.

Comment: Yes i am trying to do that ...my goal is to migrate itextpdf to some other pdf library which is open source. I am trying to do it through pdfbox..

Comment: OK. Have you learned how to use PDFBox? PDFBox has a completely different API than iText. Thus, learn using it (studying the examples, creating some small HelloWorlds,...) before trying to port your iText based code.

Comment: Ok, you have added a bounty to get more detailed responses. First of all, stack overflow is no code writing service, so don't expect someone to do your whole job for you. But if you want help in converting, you should explain the requirements. Looking at your code in detail I see an iText anti pattern - a lossy copy of an original PDF with a given title in the metadata. Is that the intention?

Comment: @mkl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77904586/pdfbox-not-loading-the-content  i am looking for the solution in my latest post ... not the overall code but the ...actually i added bounty coz i can't add it to the latest question .. just need some more modifications

Comment: Well, essentially @Tilman in his latest comment tells you what the main issue was there, you simply did not return the PDF via the servlet output stream...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PDFbox and itextpdf both are using a different approach, itextpdf skipping the html part
you would first have to take a look what the itextpdf would have generated, re-create the same in html, then feed that into the html-to-pdf converter.

We can use openhtmltopdf-pdfbox and flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf...

open source libraries are : --

org.apache.pdfbox
pdfbox
3.0.1

org.apache.pdfbox
    fontbox
    3.0.1



    org.apache.pdfbox
    pdfbox-tools
    3.0.1

we can use as they doesn't require the license

Answer (score 0):

PDDocument will do both reading and writing, so the code would be something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displaypdf.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void displaypdf(HttpServletRequest p_objRequest, HttpServletResponse p_objResponse,
        @RequestParam("filename") String p_sFilename) throws Exception {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.DISPLAYPDF);
    }
    Blob l_bContent = null;
    String l_sTcn = (String) p_objRequest.getSession().getAttribute(ClmSrConstant.TCN);
    ServletOutputStream l_objServletOutputStream = p_objResponse.getOutputStream();
    Map<String, Object> l_mapConfigFile = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        l_mapConfigFile = m_objClinicalService.retrieveMap(l_sTcn);
        Iterator<String> it = l_mapConfigFile.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            if (key.contains(p_sFilename)) {
                l_bContent = (Blob) l_mapConfigFile.get(key);
            }
        }
        if (l_bContent != null) {
            p_objResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
            byte[] l_bytes = l_bContent.getBytes(1, (int) l_bContent.length());
            InputStream l_inptStrm = new ByteArrayInputStream(l_bytes);

            // Use PDDocument 
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(l_inptStrm);

            document.save(l_objServletOutputStream);
            document.close();
        } else {
            p_objResponse.setContentType(ClmSrConstant.TXT_CNTN_TYP);
            p_objResponse.getOutputStream().print(ClmSrConstant.NLP_REPORT_ERROR);
        }

        l_objServletOutputStream.flush();
        l_objServletOutputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception exExp) {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.error(ClmSrDebugConstant.EXCEP_DISPLAYPDF, exExp);
        }
    }
}
```