# PDFBox not loading the content

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displaypdf.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void displaypdf(HttpServletRequest p_objRequest, HttpServletResponse p_objResponse,
            @RequestParam("filename") String p_sFilename) throws Exception {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.DISPLAYPDF);
        }
        String l_sReportName;
        Blob l_bContent = null;
        String l_sTcn = (String) p_objRequest.getSession().getAttribute(ClmSrConstant.TCN);
        ServletOutputStream l_objServletOutputStream = p_objResponse.getOutputStream();
        Map<String, Object> l_mapConfigFile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Document document = null;
        try {
            l_mapConfigFile = m_objClinicalService.retrieveMap(l_sTcn);
            Iterator<String> it = l_mapConfigFile.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                if (key.contains(p_sFilename)) {
                    l_bContent = (Blob) l_mapConfigFile.get(key);
                }
            }
            l_sReportName = p_sFilename;
            if (l_bContent != null) {
p_objResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                byte[] l_bytes = l_bContent.getBytes(1, (int) l_bContent.length());
                InputStream l_inptStrm = l_bContent.getBinaryStream();                
PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(l_bytes);
                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                doc.addPage(page);
                String fileName = "C:\\Users\\dhs\\new.pdf";
                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String text = stripper.getText(doc);
                
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new 
                PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                contentStream.beginText();

                contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.TIMES_ROMAN), 12);
                contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 500);
                text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                contentStream.showText(text);

                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close(); 
                doc.save(fileName);
                
}
else {
                p_objResponse.setContentType(ClmSrConstant.TXT_CNTN_TYP);
                p_objResponse.getOutputStream().print(ClmSrConstant.NLP_REPORT_ERROR);
            }

            l_objServletOutputStream.flush();
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }
            l_objServletOutputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception exExp) {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error(ClmSrDebugConstant.EXCEP_DISPLAYPDF, exExp);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

The pdf which is downloaded in system
[image]

**using the pdfbox version as**

org.apache.pdfbox
pdfbox
3.0.1

[PDF downloaded is attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w02UrCWQ4bnj7uJ5HQA6QG2fFHpTpJAP/view?usp=drive_link)

**Two chalenges i am facing with pdfbox is**

**1. i just only need to show the bytes data to pdf, no addition or updation to the pdf required, just the exact pdf which i get through the bytes data**

**2. i am able to save the pdf in pdfbox , which is through doc.save() but , requirement is to display it in UI, not to save... looked for solution but no help as of now**

Comment: Please share the PDF that has been generated by your code. And please indicate exactly which PDFBox version you are using.

Comment: Please share the PDF that has been generated by your code. I.e. not a screenshot but the actual PDF file. Stack overflow itself does not allow arbitrary file attachments, but you can use other file sharing options (like google drive or dropbox public shares) and post the URL here.

Comment: At first glance the PDF looks ok. And it does contain the second page you add in your code as expected. Which PDF viewer displays the error and fails to load the PDF?

Comment: There is a second page … This is the overall code which I shared … pdfbox is the library here I used..no additional viewer here

Comment: what software displayed "failed to load the document"? I'm able to display both pages with firefox, pdfdebugger, adobe reader and chrome.

Comment: Really …I am using Chrome and ie both showing fail to display

Comment: Are you displaying it from the file system or from a webserver?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i have updated the code and displying the pdf through this method

Comment: You're not passing the PDF to `l_objServletOutputStream`, you're only saving to a file.

Comment: yes i need to pass but how can i do that...

Comment: Well, instead of saving to a file you can save to an OutputStream...

Comment: just save to `l_objServletOutputStream`, because that is of type `OutputStream`.

Comment: let me try to save to outputstream

Comment: Considering your recent edit, *"i just only need to show the bytes data to pdf, no addition or updation to the pdf required, just the exact pdf which i get through the bytes data"* - then why do you use a PDF library at all, why don't you simply write `l_bytes` to `l_objServletOutputStream`?

Comment: @mkl is it possible that we can connect

Comment: @dhS *"is it possible that we can connect"* - we do connect here, don't we? ;) Other than that, if you have individual consulting on your mind, that would be possible but it would be subject to my normal consultancy rates...

Comment: @mkl yes we are connected :) ... just have some confusions ... as you said that can be directly done "simply write l_bytes to l_objServletOutputStream" ...i got suggestions for  pdfbox  that can help us in future enhancements ... confused between the two approaches .. i think i can fix now

Comment: *"i got suggestions for pdfbox that can help us in future enhancements"* - that indeed is possible, you then would load the document as you already do, manipulate it as part of the enhancement, and eventually save it to the servlet output stream.

Comment: @DuncG *"You would have a better chance of an answer if you stripped the example code to the basics - get rid of servlet + configs"* - In general you are right but not in this case. Because the error is in the way the OP returns the result PDF to the servlet response (or more to the point, does _not_ return it). He originally had a stripped-down example of which we only could say, yes, that works fine.

Comment: @dhS Have you meanwhile tried writing the PDF to the `ServletOutputStream l_objServletOutputStream`, either from `doc.save` or directly using `l_bytes`?

Comment: @dhS use `l_objServletOutputStream.write(l_bytes);`

Comment: @Tilman i have used pdfbox for future enhancement in code so i have used doc.save(l_objServletOutputStream); ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mkl and @Tilman Thanks for the support .. this is the final solution which i updated that it might help someone who's looking for solution.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/displaypdf.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void displaypdf(HttpServletRequest p_objRequest, HttpServletResponse p_objResponse,
                @RequestParam("filename") String p_sFilename) throws Exception {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.DISPLAYPDF);
            }
            String l_sReportName;
            Blob l_bContent = null;
            String l_sTcn = (String) p_objRequest.getSession().getAttribute(ClmSrConstant.TCN);
            ServletOutputStream l_objServletOutputStream = p_objResponse.getOutputStream();
            Map<String, Object> l_mapConfigFile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            
            try {
                l_mapConfigFile = m_objClinicalService.retrieveMap(l_sTcn);
                Iterator<String> it = l_mapConfigFile.keySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String key = it.next();
                    if (key.contains(p_sFilename)) {
                        l_bContent = (Blob) l_mapConfigFile.get(key);
                    }
                }
                l_sReportName = p_sFilename;
                PDDocument doc = null;
                if (l_bContent != null) {
                    p_objResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    byte[] l_bytes = l_bContent.getBytes(1, (int) l_bContent.length());
                    //InputStream l_inptStrm = l_bContent.getBinaryStream();
                    //text added by pdfbox changes begining
                    doc = Loader.loadPDF(l_bytes);
                    PDDocumentInformation pdd = doc.getDocumentInformation();  
                    pdd.setTitle(l_sReportName);   
                    doc.save(l_objServletOutputStream);
                        //text added by pdfbox changes end

// if we are not using pdfbox we can directly pass the bytes to the outputstream
//l_objServletOutputStream.write(l_bytes);
                } else {
                    p_objResponse.setContentType(ClmSrConstant.TXT_CNTN_TYP);
                    l_objServletOutputStream.print(ClmSrConstant.NLP_REPORT_ERROR);
                }
    
                l_objServletOutputStream.flush();
                if (doc != null) {
                    doc.close();
                }
                l_objServletOutputStream.close();
    
            } catch (Exception exExp) {
                    LOGGER.error(ClmSrDebugConstant.EXCEP_DISPLAYPDF, exExp);
            }
        }
```

Comment: minor unrelated pet peeves: `LOGGER.error()` is called only if debug is enabled, that doesn't make sense; `p_objResponse.getOutputStream()` is called twice.